# set of directions for an array to follow in C

Tags: arrays, c, shapes

So for my coding class (in C), we had to write a program that would fill a square of N >=4 elements in a certain manner (from left to right and then down and then right to left to go up and end at the origin).

After a while, and getting a solution with layers repeating the set of instructions for each circle we get this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4

int main(void){
    int map[N][N];
    int dirs[4][2] = {
            {0, 1},
            {1, 0},
            {0, -1},
            {-1, 0}
    };
    for (int layer=0; layer < (N+1)/2; layer++){
        // for each layer the starting point is (layer, layer)
        // for each layer and each direction the number of repeat is N - layer*2 -1
        int x=layer, y=layer;
        int number = 1;
        map[x][y] = number; // in case of N is odd
        for (int dir=0; dir < 4; dir ++){
            for (int i=0; i<N-layer*2-1; i++){
                map[x][y] = number;
                number ++;
                x = x + dirs[dir][0];
                y = y + dirs[dir][1];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Final map is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%4d ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Final map is: 
   1    2    3    4 
  12    1    2    5 
  11    4    3    6 
  10    9    8    7 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But I don't understand why do we put the supposed last instruction {0,1} (meaning go up 1 element and stay on said column) as the first instruction, considering we start counting from 1 and end up at 4 by repeating the {0,1} instruction N-layer*2-1 times (3 if n=4 and in the first layer).

Shouldn't dirs be:

```
 int dirs[4][2] = {
          
           {1, 0},
           {0, -1},
           {-1, 0},
           {0, 1}
    };
```

Comment: _"we start counting from 1 and end up at 4..."_  `C` indexing for `int map[N][N];` array actually goes from `int map[0][0]` through `map[N-1][N-1]`.  (which is what your code is doing here:  `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){`  ( same is true for `int dirs[4][2]` )

Comment: Yes, hence why we first do the "outer" layer and the the "inside" layer which starts from (1,1), but to count from (0,0) we would go right 3 times, thats why I don't get why in the array dirs the first element is {0,1}

Comment: I've understood now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(0,1) means moving from column y=0 to column y=1 thus moving rightwards (ryyker's comment enlightens this).